# mount ignores umask option in /etc/fstab for NTFS drive

Tags: linux, mount, ntfs, file-permissions, fstab

I have a 1TB NTFS drive that I'm trying to mount using `/etc/fstab` at boot.

The entry in `/etc/fstab` looks like this:

`UUID=0C6C7C9D6C7C82EE /mnt/ext1tb ntfs umask=707 0 2`

The drive gets properly mounted to `/mnt/ext1tb` but executing `stat -c %A /mnt/ext1tb/` yields in `d---rwx---`, which isn't `707`, resulting in me not being able to write/read to/from it using my primary user account.

I've tried remounting the drive multiple times and using `777` as the `umask` with no success. Mounting the drive directly with `mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/ext1tb -o umask=707` yields the same results.

Using latest arch linux with 4.17 kernel.

Comment: The `d---rwx---` you report is precisely the effect of `umask 0707`. In effect the requested permissions are masked with the complement of the `umask` value (`perms=reqperms&~umval`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

umask does not directly specify the mode; it specifies the mask applied to the base mode, telling it which bits to clear (but not which ones to set).

Perhaps unintuitively, it is also inverted: a 0 bit means "don't change", but a 1 bit means "clear (mask out) this bit". So 0707 clears all user/world bits and 0777 clears everything.

What you want is either 0, 07, or 077 (depending on whether the files should be group- and world-readable).

Comment: Thanks! It didn't dawn on me that it's a mask. (despite it being in the name..)